# Is there an ActiveRecord framework for node.js and PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, node.js, activerecord

I'm new to Node.js and coming from the Rails world, I'm fond of the ActiveRecord pattern/framework it provides.  Is there anything like it for node?  Or am I stuck with building queries?  Also, Postgres is my database of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Tower.js.  More of a full stack framework built on top of Express.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a Rails-like framework in Node that I'm aware is Express http://expressjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Railway.js](http://railwayjs.com/) is like padrino, a full stack modularized framework for Node.js. Tower.js is inspired by Rails so, it's closest match.

I'd say Express is more in tune with Sinatra than Rails, It offers view-rendering engine and url routing basically.